# undefined item in json object

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to output all values in a JSON list with `for`each, and every single time this mysterious "undefined" variable pops up. Take a look:

HTML:

```
<span id="1">

</span>
```

JavaScript:

```
var lel =
    {
        1: {
            "some": "json",
            "list": "that",
            "says": "undefined",
        },
    }

var s;

for(i in lel[1]) {
     s+= '<B>' + i + '</B>' + ": " + lel[1][i] + "<br />"; 
}

document.getElementById('1').innerHTML = s;
```

Result (in span)

```
undefined**some**: json
**list**: that
**says**: undefined
```

Where is that "undefined" thing coming from?

Comment: Depending on your browser (IE in particular), you'll want to remove the trailing commas in your array. It's a syntax error in some cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that s is initially `undefined`.

change `var s;` to `var s = '';`

Answer (score 0):

Your `s` is undefined. Try `var s = '';`